# Make div expand to full height - 30px

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way with just css to make a div expand to the full height of the page - 30px. I have a "footer" at the bottom of the page that is 30px tall and set to `position: fixed; bottom: 0px;` I don't want any of the content from the rest of the page to show behind this footer.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with your html and css please?

Comment: ..But before that, provide your code in your question

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header added just for demonstration purposes</div>
    <div id="content">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="footer">And this is my footer</div>
</div>
```

now style

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
 }

 #wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* Required to absolutely position the footer */
 }

#footer {
    height: 50px; /* Define height of the footer */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Sit it on the bottom */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /* As wide as it's allowed */
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* This should match the height of the footer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would probably place all in a wrapper and set the size to 100%,

But in new css3 you have calc() which does exactly what you need: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc

Please note that not all (even modern) browsers yet have support for calc()

Comment: did you research any of the lines after the first of your answer?

Comment: I am aware of the problems with it, thats why i said that it was a part of css3, which does not have 100% support yet

Comment: excellent, then you understand without the explicit statement that does not have full cross-browser support, some noobs will not know that it is not a universal solution. also in this realization you should note that i did not downvote your answer (effectively calling it wrong) but merely commented on it (effectively saying it required more information).